# Is there a way to automatically merge notes if commits for those notes get squashed?

Tags: git, git-notes

For example:

```
git commit -am "Something"
git notes append -m "Dark "
git commit -am "Something"
git notes append -m "Side"

git rebase -i
# now I squash two commits and I expect to see "Dark Side" here
# but it show that note is undefined
git notes show
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly your config; assuming you have otherwise default config, you need to set the `notes.rewriteRef` option to `refs/notes/commits` for this to work.

The magic command you need is thus:

```
git config notes.rewriteRef refs/notes/commits
```

After the above, squashing the commits should join the two notes.

They will have newlines between them, however; I suspect disabling that behaviour so you get things on the same line as in your example would require hacking around in the Git source code.

#### Background

From [`git help config`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) (emphasis mine):

> `notes.rewriteRef`
>
> > When copying notes during a rewrite, specifies the (fully qualified) ref whose notes should be copied. The ref may be a glob, in which case notes in all matching refs will be copied. You may also specify this configuration several times.
> >
> > Does not have a default value; you must configure this variable to enable note rewriting. **Set it to `refs/notes/commits` to enable rewriting for the default commit notes.**
> >
> > This setting can be overridden with the `GIT_NOTES_REWRITE_REF` environment variable, which must be a colon separated list of refs or globs.

(See also the descriptions for `notes.rewriteMode` and `notes.rewrite.<command>`, both of which default to the values we need, ie `concatenate` and `true` respectively.)

#### Example

Here's something similar for the above test:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository

$ git config notes.rewriteRef refs/notes/commits

$ git add a # Here's a file I created earlier

$ git commit -am 'Initial commit'
[master (root-commit) 93219cb] Initial commit
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a

$ echo a >>a

$ git commit -am 'Something'
[master 3c17aca] Something
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

$ git notes append -m 'Dark '

$ echo b >>a

$ git commit -am 'Something'
[master 6732d81] Something
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

$ git notes append -m 'Side'

$ git rebase -i HEAD~2 # Will squash the last commit into the one before and accept the default commit message.
[detached HEAD 552668b] Something
 1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.

$ git show
commit 552668b4b96e4b2f8fcd7763dcc115edd159eb89 (HEAD, master)
Author: me_and <not.an@email.address>
Date:   Wed Jan 30 10:09:10 2013 +0000

    Something

    Something

Notes:
    Dark

    Side

diff --git a/a b/a
index 7898192..4ac2bee 100644
--- a/a
+++ b/a
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
 a
+a
+b
```